# overwrite option file to user?

Tags: c#, filestream, binaryfiles

I need to create a binary file in a directory or path, if the file exists, the application  should ask to the user if want to overwrite it. I have this code to write the file, so, how can verify if the file exist and show to console the message?

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(binaryFilePath, FileMode.Create)) // destiny file directory.
            {
                using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < frameCodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(frameCodes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Exists(binaryFilePath)` should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if(File.Exists(binaryFilePath) && PromptUser())
{
...
}
```

Where `PromptUser()` will ask the user if they want to override the file

Comment: Ah, I must  have skipped over the console part.